# Image enhancement with python and OpenCV

Tags: python, image-processing, rgb, yuv

I am trying to enhance my image by first converting `RGB` color space to `YUV` color space and do histogram equalization to `Y` value.  However, the output image does not look good.

For histogram equalization, I use the method found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization).

Here is the input image:
[image]

Here is the output image:
[image]

I really don't know where the problem is, can anyone help me or give me some hint?

Below is my code,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('/Users/simon/Documents/DIP/Homework_3/input4.bmp')
shape = img.shape

Y_origin_hist = [0] * 256
U_origin = [[0 for i in range(0, shape[1])] for j in range(0, shape[0])] 
V_origin = [[0 for i in range(0, shape[1])] for j in range(0, shape[0])] 

Y_hist = [0] * 256

# Read RGB value and calculate YUV value
for i in range(0, shape[0]) :
    for j in range(0, shape[1]) :
        px = img[i,j]
        y = int(0.299 * px[2] + 0.587 * px[1] + 0.114 * px[0])
        u = int(-0.169 * px[2] - 0.331 * px[1] + 0.5 * px[0]) + 128
        v = int(0.5 * px[2] - 0.419 * px[1] - 0.081 * px[0]) + 128
        Y_origin_hist[y] = Y_origin_hist[y] + 1
        U_origin[i][j] = u
        V_origin[i][j] = v

# Histogram equalization
for i in range(0, 256) :
    Y_hist[i] = int(((sum(Y_origin_hist[0:i]) - min(Y_origin_hist) - 1) * 255) / ((shape[0] * shape[1]) - 1))

# Write back to RGB value
for i in range(0, shape[0]) :
    for j in range(0, shape[1]) :
        px = img[i,j]
        px[0] = int(Y_hist[px[0]] + 1.77216 * (U_origin[i][j] - 128) + 0.00099 * (V_origin[i][j] - 128))
        px[1] = int(Y_hist[px[1]] - 0.3437 * (U_origin[i][j] - 128) - 0.71417 * (V_origin[i][j] - 128))
        px[2] = int(Y_hist[px[2]] - 0.00093 * (U_origin[i][j] - 128) + 1.401687 * (V_origin[i][j] - 128))

cv2.imwrite('/Users/simon/Documents/DIP/Homework_3/output4.bmp', img)
```

Comment: Looks like an overflow problem. You need to clip `px[]` to the range 0..255. Also, I'm not sure it makes sense to use the original `px[]` values to index the LUT, and also to add the colour-difference components each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OpenCV in C++ the + and - operators are overloaded and they automatically prevent overflows.  However, this is not the case when using Python.  For this reason you should use `cv2.add()` and `cv2.subtract()` when doing math to get the same results that you would get using C++.